# view's frame don't change

Tags: ios, autolayout, masonry

I have a tableview.when reload data I will configure cell and update constraint. after that cell's`layoutSubviews` be invoked,but view's frame can't be update

```
- (void)configModel:(LKSportActivityEventModel *)model {
 //some code before
   CGFloat titleWidth = 100;
   [self.activityNameView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.mas_equalTo(titleWidth);
    }];
 //some code after
}
```

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setCorner:UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft
             bounds:self.activityNameView.bounds
         cornerSize:CGSizeMake(4, 4)
         targetView:self.activityNameView
              layer:self.activityNameViewShapLayer];
}
```

activityNameView's bounds don't change

Comment: mas_updateConstraints works only if you're changing the constants of the constraint, do you have a width constraint that Masonry can update? Also what's the purpose of the second part of code? Do you have something going on here?

Comment: @LorenzOliveto Get bounds before add a mask to activityNameView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.

`layoutSubviews` only computes the size and position of its subviews. It does not lay out the whole view subtree.

After `UITableViewCell.layoutSubviews`, only the `content view`'s frame is right.

The easier way to fix your layout is to call `contentView.layoutIfNeeded` inside `layoutSubviews`.